# Ordinal vs multinominal classification in XGboost: differences in one-hot encoding

Tags: boosting, ordinal-data, categorical-encoding

I have followed this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155737/what-is-the-difference-between-multinomial-and-ordinal-logistic-regression) and tried to see if there will be any difference in predicted probabilities if I use different one-hot encoding in XGboost.

This is my code with some dummy data, which is actually not ordinal in nature.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

df = load_iris(as_frame=True)['frame']
x = df[[_ for _ in df.columns if _ != 'target']]
y = df['target']

model = XGBClassifier()

y1 = pd.get_dummies(y)
y2 = pd.get_dummies(y)
y2.loc[np.where(y==1)[0], [1,2]] = 1
y2.loc[np.where(y==2)[0], :] = 1

m1 = model.fit(x,y1)
m2 = model.fit(x,y2)

print(m1.predict_proba(x) == m2.predict_proba(x))
```

The predicted scores are exactly the same, so I am unsure if the difference in encoding does anything in XGBoost.

How can XGBoost handle ordinal classification then?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hitting undetermined behaviour here as XGBoost is not designed to have `y` be a `pandas.DataFrame`. I suspect that the `sklearn` API casts this into some `numpy` array but after than all bets are off. It appears it does something like one a classification task per column.

Strictly speaking XGBoost does not support ordinal regression, we can *roughly* approximate it to some degree by using multi-class classification as surrogate. i.e. having `mlogloss` (multi-class log-loss) as our evaluation metric and our objective as `multi:softprob` so we predict the probability of each data-point belonging to each class. Then we can directly change the predicted probabilities to ordinal values. The change itself can be done using two main options, without or with thresholding: A. We directly pick the class/label with the highest predicted probability (something akin to `np.argmax(predicted_probs, axis=1)` in Python) B. We apply thresholds to our predicted probability ranges to map them to ordinal values. (something akin to : `np.argmax(predicted_probs > thresholds, axis=1)` in Python).

The above being said, if we are dealing with multiple levels (e.g. 10+) and the spacing between is expected roughly equal, it might make sense to simply treat this as a regression problem directly. Similarly, if we are really aching about it, we can code the [proportional odds](https://peopleanalytics-regression-book.org/ord-reg.html) loss (aka cumulative log-odds loss) as our objective manually and use that directly. Just remember we need the loss, the gradient *and* the Hessian.

Comment: Ye, so can we you please expand on two points: (1) 'Then we can directly change the predicted probabilities to ordinal values', how exactly? and (2) What I am trying to figure out is how to implement the loss, gradient and Hessian given the proportional odds loss. In the post, I've written what I think is the loss (loglikelihood, cross-entropy) given the proportional odds assumption, but for this, I think you need to treat this as a binary problem, no? Can you please expand? Thanks.

Comment: (1). There are two options, without or with thresholding: A. We directly pick the class/label with the highest predicted probability (something akin to `np.argmax(predicted_probs, axis=1)` in Python) B. We apply thresholds to our predicted probability ranges to map them to ordinal values. (something akin to :  `np.argmax(predicted_probs > thresholds, axis=1)` in Python). (2) Apologies, I don't see any loss in your post; (in any case) we can see this as a binary problem where we predict the cumulative probability of the j-th ordinal value for the i-th observation. (cont.)

Comment: Then our response is an indicator variable that is 1 if the target variable for the i-th observation is less than or equal to the j-th ordinal value, and 0 otherwise. So when we have something like $y_{ij} \log(\hat{p}_{ij})$ in our loss we represent the contribution to the loss from the correct predictions as this part is maximized when the predicted probability is equal to $1$ for the correct ordinal value. ($\hat{p}_{ij}$ being the predicted cumulative probability of the j-th ordinal value for the i-th observation.)

Comment: hey, no sorry, it's another post actually this one (I mixed them up): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631367/ordinal-log-loss-in-a-multiclass-classification-in-xgboost?noredirect=1#comment1178692_631367. I describe there what problems I have with implementing the proportional odds assumptions.

Comment: OK, anyway I will edit this post such it includes the clarifications for point 1. Let's keep them separately so it is clear what is asked and answered.